# can i use jQuery in Django framework

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I'm writing a Django Full website 
and trying to change the element using jQuery OR JavaScript but I couldn't

I want to change the total

```
<tr>
    <td>{{i.itemname}}</td>
    <td>{{i.description}}</td>
    <td id="quantity">{{i.quantity}}</td>
    <td id="price">{{i.price}}</td>
    <td id="total"></td>
</tr>
```

---

```
var quantity = document.getElementById('#quantity')
var price = document.getElementById('#price')
q=Number(quantity)
p=Number(price)
total = q*p 
document.getElementById("#total").innerHTML = total;
```

Comment: You don't use `#` prefix in `getElementById()`. Also suspect you might be  duplicating `id` if those are repeating rows. ID's must be unique by definition. And you can't pass an element directly to `Number()`....you want it's text value first

Comment: i use # prefix in getElementById() and now i convert the total number to string and still the same nothing change

Comment: Start by checking errors thrown in browser dev tools console

Comment: i check there is no errors :|

Comment: what is your issue? what errors are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

HTML:

```
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td id="test">Rakib</td>
            <td>Islam</td>
            <td id="quantity">5</td>
            <td id="price">5</td>
            <td id="total"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Javascript:

```
    <script type ="text/javascript">
        var quantity = document.getElementById('quantity');
        var price = document.getElementById('price');
        q=Number(quantity.innerText);
        p=Number(price.innerText);
        total1 = q*p;
        document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total1;
    </script>
```